# how do you print stars n amount of times on multiple lines using prolog

Tags: prolog

i need to print stars '*' n amount of time

Comment: Where is `put` defined? `*` by itself isn't a valid term in Prolog. You would need `'*'` if you want an atom representing the character `*`. Also, Prolog does not evaluate expressions in-line. So `star(N-1)` does not subtract 1 from `N` and use that as the argument for the `star` call. `star(N).` by itself does nothing with `N` so has no clear meaning. I would recommend working through some basic Prolog tutorials (there are a few online) before attempting to write a Prolog program.

Comment: *at the moment i have done this...* actually, I believe @damianodamiano had done it in his answer, and you included it in a subsequent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
star(0).
star(N):-
    N > 0,
    foreach(between(1,N,_),write('*')),nl,
    N1 is N-1,
    star(N1).

?- star(3).
***
**
*
true
false
```

One of the problem in your code is that if you call `star` with `N-1`, at the next iteration `N` will be unified with `N-1` (as you write it, it does not performs the arithmetic operation). Instead you should do `N1 is N-1` and then call star with `N-1`. Then there are other problems... Look at my code to have an idea.

Comment: how do i get it to print out like this:
each set of stars on a new line.
***
**
*
**
***

Comment: also how would you get rid of the true and false and only print the stars

Comment: if you don't want the new line, remove the nl. You cannot remove the true

Comment: i do want the new line. i want it to print out 3 stars then 2 stars then 1 star then back to 2 stars then back to 3 stars

Comment: so like in the above example to showed me i have changed it to the output i wanted

Comment: @g.s you don't edit answers to reply, you reply and then the answerer may edit it.