# how do i print out stars using prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to print out stars on one line and then n-1 on the next until one star, and then back to n amount.

Comment: `((2*N)-1)) is N > 0,` this is *really* convolute... what do you mean ? Keep your code simple, and just write a loop that goes from 1 N. Maybe factorize out the (ugly) print of N * in a mini one-liner...

Comment: You have a partial solution to your earlier ask at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268954/how-do-you-print-stars-n-amount-of-times-on-multiple-lines-using-prolog. It would be more appropriate to edit that question to clarify it than to ask an altogether new one.

Comment: *so far i have managed to print then like this:*... well, technically, the code you have so far is a direct copy of an answer from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

What about as follows?

```
line(N) :-
  foreach(between(1, N, _), write('*')),
  nl.

star(1) :-
  line(1).

star(N) :-
  line(N),
  NM1 is N-1,
  star(NM1),
  line(N).
```

Calling `star(N)`.

Comment: that works thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
%this is the main function you want to call
star(N) :-
  starl(N),
  starr(1,N).

% counts down from n to zero and 
% writes according amount of stars
starl(0):- !.
starl(N):-
  write_n_times("*", N),
  Nm is N-1,
  starl(Nm).

% counts up from X to Np and 
% writes according amount of stars
starr(N, N):- write_n_times("*", N), !.
starr(X, Np):-
  write_n_times("*", X),
  Xp is X+1,
  starr(Xp, Np).


% writes X for I times and makes then a new line
write_n_times(_,0) :- nl, !.
write_n_times(X,I) :-
  write(X),
  Im is I - 1,
  write_n_times(X,Im).
```

Comment: it needs to be done in one function so when you call star(3).the answer above should be display

Comment: when you call star(3). it gives you exactly what you want. If you want a solution without helper-methods you need to mention it in your problem description ...

Comment: this does not work it causes an error

Comment: I'm using swi-prolog and it works. What error message do you get?

Comment: Undefined procedure: starr1/1

Comment: yes because there is no function starr/1 there is only a starr/2 and a star/1. One r less at the end and it should work. I chose starr and starl because I meant starRIGHT and starLEFT. Now i see that the naming wasn't maybe the best ;)