# Writing a prolog star/1 program

Tags: prolog

I was tasked to write up a program that ,given a list of N integers as argument, prints N rows, each row
with X stars, where X in an element in the list. And I was given this example:

```
   ?-printstars([4,3,4,2]). 
    ****
    ***
    ****
    **
```

Attempts to make it have not went well.

```
foreach([]).
foreach([N|R]) :- stars(N), foreach(R).
```

Solutions have only produced:

```
?- stars(4).
ERROR: Unknown procedure: stars/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your attempt at the solution for `stars`?  Hint is that it'll resemble your `foreach` except it will decrement an integer instead of shrinking a list, and it will print a `*` instead of calling `stars`.

Comment: Well, I added that. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Take a look at this answer and try to fit it to your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268954/how-do-you-print-stars-n-amount-of-times-on-multiple-lines-using-prolog

Comment: That error is because you have not defined the `stars` predicate. So the prolog top level is asking you to do the same thing I am: please try to define the `stars` predicate :) If you write part of a definition and it's not working correctly, we can try to help you understand why. But for now, the answer to your question is: try defining the predicate.

Comment: "DWIM could not correct goal" may be a somewhat confusing message. "Even looking for an approximate match yielded nothing" would be more illuminating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursion is a good idea here:

```
printstars([]).
printstars([0 | R]) :- nl, printstars(R), !.
printstars([A | B]) :- write("*"), K is A - 1, printstars([K | B]).
```

Comment: Recursion is a good idea but not the best idea for this task. This particular solution does a very strange thing anyway, where it uses different clauses to do the "inside" and "outside" loop in the same predicate. It is a bit peculiar.

Comment: Try giving your solution the following query: `?- printstars([-1]).` You can see the answer by @Enigmativity to see how to fix this.

Comment: @TA_intern Sure, the negatives would make the program go completely crazy, but I don't think that is the point in OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You had half of the predicates right. You just needed to define `stars/1`.

```
foreach([]).
foreach([N|R]) :- stars(N), foreach(R).

stars(0) :- nl.
stars(N) :-
    N > 0,
    write("*"),
    N2 is N - 1,
    stars(N2).
```

```
?- foreach([2,3,2,1]).
**
***
**
*
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since printing is a side effect, it would be cleaner if you used forall/2, like this:

```
print_stars(L) :-
    forall(member(X, L), stars(X)).

stars(X) :-
    forall(between(1, X, _), write(*)),
    nl.
```

In addition, in SWI-Prolog, you can use the following formatting specifier to print a sequence of N stars:

```
format("~`*t~*+", [N]).
```

With this you can get rid of the second loop:

```
print_stars(L) :-
    forall(member(X, L), format("~`*t~*+~n", [X]).
```